# jquery slidedown/slideup crazy effect on nested lists

Tags: jquery, css, submenu, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to make a mouseenter/mouseleave accordion-like menu.

If you look at the page, you'll see the menu on the left side, try to mouseover on some element and then try to mouseover on some element below and you'll the crazy slidedown/slideup crazy effect I'm talking about.

You can see the issue here in this video: http://quick.as/o34oiqpw. And here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/pu2sH/2/.

The jquery is this:

```
$('ul li').on('mouseenter', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('ul:first',this).slideDown();
    }).on('mouseleave',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('ul:first',this).slideUp();
    });
```

The html is a simple ul li ul li ul li.

I don't know how to 'attack' this issue. I've thought of some kind of delay on the slideup but I don't know how to implement it.

Any advice on this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: let me know if the below code works or not

Comment: I think it's better than before, but not completely solved. Also, I had to create a funciton to toggle ani and pass that function as callback to the slideUp/slideDown.

Comment: if you isolate the problem to a fiddle i can help you troubleshoot it

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pu2sH/2/ and here's a video of the issue: http://quick.as/o34oiqpw. You can see the crazy list going up and down up and down when you hover too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'd want to edit this code:

```
   $('.menu-lateral .acordeon li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('.children:first',this).slideDown();
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('.children:first',this).slideUp();
    });
```

To maybe something like this:

```
   var ani = false;
   $(document).ready(function(){  
       //other init code...

       $('.menu-lateral .acordeon li').on('mouseenter', function() {
                if (!ani){
                    ani = true;
                    $('.children:first',this).slideDown(function(){ ani = false;});
                 }
         }).on('mouseleave', function() {
                if (!ani){
                    ani = true;
                    $('.children:first',this).slideUp(function(){ ani = false;});
                }
          });
    });
```